# installed memcache, no noticeable improvements

Tags: 6, caching

I just installed varnish and memcache on my server. Varnish works great but I don't really know how memcache should perform. I can't see any improvements for authenticated users.

I turned on memcache statistics and saw that it is working but I can't see a noticeable improvements in the page loading time.

Any ideas on how I can improve performance for authenticated users for an existing website?

Thanks, M.

Comment: Improving performance for authenticated users is a non-trivial topic, and you're unlikely to get "a good answer" without breaking the question down significantly. The solution will vary from site to site.

Comment: did you try cloudflare.com? the basic account is free and has some very good caching. how much is the cache filled of memcache?

Comment: Hmm..I noticed something similar or to say memcache hurting page load times - http://serverfault.com/questions/445223/is-memcache-impacting-my-performence-negatively

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to try/use Authcache module

http://drupal.org/project/authcache

Make sure to configure it with memcache by adding the following line in your settings file

```
$conf['cache_inc'] = './modules/authcache/api/authcache.inc';
```